# Python packaging problem. Module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I would like to create a Python package called `nice_package`.

This is how the structure of the folder looks like.

```
nice_package (folder)
setup.py
- nice_package (subfolder)
  __init__.py
  nice_package.py
- - utils (subsubfolder)
    __init__.py
    some_function.py
```

In setup.py I have

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import numpy as np

setup(
        name = 'nice_package',
        version = '1.0',
        packages=['nice_package'],
        install_requires=['numpy', 
                          'scipy'],
      )
```

At the beginning of nice_package.py I `from utils.some_function import some_other_function`.

When I try to call

import nice_package.nice_package

I get the error that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.some_function'.

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your setuptools, that might do the trick.

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```